# asking question about using curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);

Tags: php, curl

I studied yahoo app login page by curls that user can check his/her user and pass

in this line:

```
$postData = "login=$login&passwd=$password&.src=&.tries=5&.bypass=
&.partner=&.md5=&.hash=&.intl=us&.tries=1&.challenge=ydKtXwwZarNeRMeAufKa56.oJqaO
&.u=dmvmk8p231bpr&.yplus=&.emailCode=&pkg=&stepid=
&.ev=&hasMsgr=0&.v=0&.chkP=N&.last=&.done=" . $serviceUrl;
```

by using curl can some one explain these ampersand and dots? why they are used here?
I know about hashing and MD5 but I don't know about these dots and....

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
```

Comment: Smells fishy... there seems to be `&` missing after `$login`, and those dots.. while perfectly valid, it's strange to have variable names starting with a dot. Moreover, there are two `.tries=`, so unless the query string is parsed manually, the first value will be lost

Comment: $login is the name of username and $password is the password they don't need ampersand but for anothers I don't have idea about them

Comment: I think maybe for using curls it should add the dots yes?

Comment: it is confusing but it is working

Comment: hmmm, dots get converted to underscores when used as a GET/POST parameter key in PHP. i.e. `.src` => `$_GET['_src']`

Answer (score 0):

& is fairly fundamental syntax for connecting different parameters together in http requests.   The "." seems to be just variable 'style' that yahoo uses.  Nothing special about it all.

It could also be the case that the PHP code that was used to create that was messed up, parsed wrong and the dots shouldn't be there in the first place.

Comment: what you mean with the first place?

Comment: would you please tell me what is dmvmk8p231bpr? is it a public key for hashing?